# An underscore, a dot and a dash must always be followed by one or more alphanumeric characters without using Regex

Tags: java, email-validation

I'm working on a school assignment that validates emails without using Regex. The premise of this exercise is to learn about methods and to practice our critical thinking. I understand that the code can be reduced to fewer lines.

Right now, I need to check all conditions for the prefix of an email (The characters before '@'):

- It contains at least one character.
- It contains only alphanumeric characters, underscores(‘_’), periods(‘.’), and dashes(‘-’).
- **An underscore, a period, or a dash must always be followed by one or more alphanumeric characters.**
- The first character must be alphanumeric.

Examples of valid prefixes are: “abc-d”, “abc.def”, “abc”, “abc_def”.
Examples of invalid prefixes are: “abc-”, “abc..d”, “.abc”, “abc#def”.

I'm having a hard time figuring out the third condition. So far, I have these methods that meet the other conditions.

```
public static boolean isAlphanumeric(char c) {
    return Character.isLetterOrDigit(c);
}

public static boolean isValidPrefixChar(char preChar) {
    char[] prefixChar = new char[] {'-', '.', '_'};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < prefixChar.length; i++) {
        if (prefixChar[i] == preChar) {
            return true;
        } else if (isAlphanumeric(preChar)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isValidPrefix(String emailPrefix) {
    boolean result = false;
    
    // To check if first character is alphanumeric
    if (isAlphanumeric(emailPrefix.charAt(0)) && emailPrefix.length() > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < emailPrefix.length(); i++) {
            // If email prefix respects all conditions, change result to true
            if (isValidPrefixChar(emailPrefix.charAt(i))) {
                result = true;
            } else {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your list:

- It contains at least one character.
- It contains only alphanumeric characters, underscores(‘_’), periods(‘.’), and dashes(‘-’).
- An underscore, a period, or a dash must always be followed by one or more alphanumeric characters.
- The first character must be alphanumeric.

As you say, 1, 2, and 4 are easy. Here's what I would do. My first line would check length and return false if incorrect. I would then iterate over the characters. Inside the loop;

- set boolean lastWasSpecial = false.
- Check that it's a legal character (condition 2)
- If index == 0, check that it's alphanumeric (condition 4)
- If it's one of the specials:

  - If lastWasSpecial is set, return false
  - Set lastWasSpecial = true;
- else set lastWasSpecial = false again

Should be about 10 lines of easily-readable code.

Comment: What do you mean by "If lastWasSpecial is set, return false?"

Comment: @zhuchini: this is actually the approach I'd recommend.  Joseph Larson is recommending: 1) check string length, and "reject" the string immediately if the check fails.  2) Otherwise, parse the string a character at a time. Use a boolean [flag variable](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-of-flag-in-programming/), "lastWasSpecial".  Set it "true" every time you encounter a "_", ".", "-".  If the next character is *ALSO* a special character, then you know the entire string is invalid.  Clean and efficient :)  Be sure to "upvote" responses you found helpful (presumably, all three replies).

Comment: @zhuchini I meant to keep a boolean value called lastWasSpecial, which means that the previous character was one of the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

## local-part

FYI, the portion of the address before the COMMERCIAL AT sign (`@`) is called a [local-part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part).

## Avoid `char`

Your code using the `char` will break when encountering characters outside the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). As a 16-bit value, `char` cannot represent most characters.

## Code points

Use code points instead, when working with individual characters. A code point is the number assigned permanently to each of the over 140,000 characters defined in Unicode.

```
int[] codePoints = localPart.codePoints().toArray() ;
```

Define a array, list, or set of your acceptable punctuation characters.

```
int codePoint = "-".codePointAt( 0 ) ;  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
```

To  verify that every punctuation character encountered is followed by a letter/digit, first make sure the punctuation mark is not the last character. If not, then look ahead on the array for the following code point. Test if that code point [is a letter or digit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(int)).

```
if( Character.isLetterOrDigit( codePoints[ i + 1 ] ) ) { … }
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm can be optimised, but I tried to change just some lines and to use the same code style. I added the explanation in the comments.

```java
public static boolean isAlphanumeric(char c) {
    return Character.isLetterOrDigit(c);
}

public static boolean isValidPrefixChar(char preChar) {
    char[] prefixChar = new char[]{'-', '.', '_'};

    for (int i = 0; i < prefixChar.length; i++) {
        if (prefixChar[i] == preChar) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isValidPrefix(String emailPrefix) {
    boolean result = false;

    // To check if first character is alphanumeric
    if (isAlphanumeric(emailPrefix.charAt(0)) && emailPrefix.length() > 1) {
        // this boolean is set to true when the next char has to be alphanumeric
        boolean nextHasToBeAlphaNumeric = false;

        // the for loop start from 1 because char 0 has been already checked
        for (int i = 1; i < emailPrefix.length(); i++) {
            // If email prefix respects all conditions, change result to true
            char character = emailPrefix.charAt(i);
            if (isValidPrefixChar(character)) {
                // the previous char is '.', '_', '-' then you cannot have two valid prefix char together
                if (nextHasToBeAlphaNumeric) {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    // the next char has to be alphanumeric
                    result = true;
                    nextHasToBeAlphaNumeric = true;
                }
            } else if (isAlphanumeric(character)) {
                result = true;
                nextHasToBeAlphaNumeric = false;
            } else {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Is there a way to include the 'isAlphanumeric' method inside the 'isValidPrefixChar' method?